# how to custome shape prograss bar like as apple shape in android?

Tags: java, android

[image]

Above image to apple shape to progress bar in android studio, so please how to use ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to create a custom view which extends `ProgressBar`, override the `onDraw()` method and draw your custom shape on the canvas.